# data sent to the printer when i click print

Tags: windows, printing, usb, driver

I'm doing a project to build printer using a microcontroller via USB. The MCU's USB is configured as printer class when I plug the MCU into the PC so that it is identified as a printer. I've installed generic/text only driver available with windows and hence i can see my printer in "devices and printers" listed under printer category.
    My question here is if I want to print whatever is sent to the printer, I need to know the data being sent from PC. For example, if I print a pdf, I want to know what data is sent i mean the format like HEX values or anything like that. Once I know what is coming into the controller I can print.
    Any input here is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since your printer setting is a simple `generic/text only`, the data sent will be the text content of the PDF. No markup, not even bold text or italics. Any pictures in the PDF will not be sent at all.

If you wan more than that, you can write a driver for your printer. As the driver writer, you determine what's sent to the printer.

Comment: Thanks MSalters,
      Suppose I'm sending a pdf with only text for the moment... what is the format of that text? whether it is sent as an ascii value in HEX?